# User prompt to select a specific workbook and specific sheet within that workbook to cut and paste into current workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

This code allows me to choose a file and open it, but when I enter the sheet name it gives me

> runtime error 91: block variable not set

This code does not close the workbook `wb` after opening it because I wanted to make sure it was at least opening the workbook, which it is.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Macro is run on a specific sheet of any workbook (even better if it can be run and automatically navigate to that sheet - the name of the sheet will always be the same, even if the workbook this is run on isn't)
2. Macro prompts user to choose a file and then choose a sheet within that file by name.
   I want to check if the sheet name entered does not exist.
3. Macro cuts specific section of that sheet and pastes it to the sheet in the workbook where the Macro was initially run.

```vb
Sub ChooseImportSheet()

Dim w As String, wb As Workbook, myFile As Office.FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .Allow MultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)

    w = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
    Workbooks.Open(wb)
    wb.Sheets(w).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("ThisWorkbook").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Sheets.Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Paste

    Application.Screen Updating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub ChooseImportSheet()

    Dim w As String, wb As Workbook, FileSelected
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    Set wsDest = ActiveSheet               'capture the active sheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileSelected)  'reference the opened workbook
    
    w = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
    On Error Resume Next          'ignore error if no matching sheet
    Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets(w)  'try to get the worksheet
    On Error GoTo 0               'stop ignoring errors
    
    If wsSrc Is Nothing Then      'sheet not found?
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & w & "' was not found in " & wb.Name
    Else
        With wsSrc.Range("A1")
            Debug.Print "Copying from " & .Address()
            .CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A4")
        End With
    End If
   
    'wb.Close false
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: (I assumed you meant "FileSelected as String") This was a perfect solution thank you so much.

Comment: Wait, sorry.. I thought it was working but I guess I was wrong. It's giving me a subscript out of range error now.

Comment: It's working on one workbook but not another - is it possible this has to do with whether or not macros are enabled?

Comment: What line is the error on?  If it's on `Set wsSrc = wb.Worksheets(w)` then make sure your VBA error handling option is set to "Break in class module" and not "Break on all errors"   If it runs at all then macros are enabled, so that's not a factor.

Comment: Still isn't working.. now it isn't working on any sheets. It says the error is on line zero. The only change I made to your code was to set FileSelected as string. I am confused because when I type the code manually (instead of copy-paste) it was working, but not on all sheets and now I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: What is happening is that it will go through the entire process without breaking or giving me an error anymore. It lets me choose a file, it opens the file, it lets me type in the sheet name, and then nothing happens (unless I add a close line, then the workbook I opened closes). When I go to the original workbook, nothing has been copied over or changed.

Comment: Still working for me.  I added in some debugging output - see if that helps figure out what's going on.